# One to one mapping in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Suppose we have two database tables `Instructor` and `Instructor_Details`. They have one to one relationship such that each instructor can have one instructor detail and one instructor detail is associated with one instructor only.

In pure database terms, `Instructor` table should be the parent of `Instructor_Details` table and the primary key of `Instructor` table should be used as foreign key in `Instructor_Details` table.

I was learning Hibernate and most of the examples of `@OneToOne` on internet have modified the tables such that the `Instructor_Details` primary key is used as foreign key in `Instructor` table, which seems contradictory as `Instructor` should be the parent of `Instructor_Details`.

How can i implement both entities in best way such that i can use the primary key of `Instructor` as foreign key in `Instructor_Details`. Also please explain the fetch types and cascade in my desired implementation. Examples with code will be very helpful.

**Edit**

Let us say the attributes for the tables are as follows:

Instructor(instructor_id (primary key), first_name, last_name)

Instructor_Details(detail_id (primary key), dob, address, instructor_id (foreign key from instructor table))

Comment: There are MANY examples of JPA 1-1 relations on the web, not sure why you cant find one that matches what you think is right (which you haven't adequately defined). http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations  If `Instructor` has an `InstructorDetails` object (and `InstructorDetails` doesnt have an `Instructor` object) then the only logical place for the FK is in the table of the owning object ... `Instructor`. If the relation is bidir, then you can choose which side has the FK.

Comment: My whole point is that since `InstructorDetails` is existence dependent on `Instructor` so the primary key of `Instructor` should be in `InstructorDetails` and that would be ideally the optimal database design. All the examples i found were putting the primary key of `InstructorDetails` as FK in `Instructor` but from conceptual point of view `InstructorDetails` should never be the parent in this case. We should not modify our database design so as to accomodate Hibernate code

Comment: @BillyFrost thanks this is what i wanted. This article explains mapping keeping RDBMS in mind. Unfortunately i didn't find this one before. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Since in pure database terms you're modeling this as parent/child you're stuck with OneToMany. What I've done in this situation, so I can keep the relationship like that and take advantage of things like on cascade delete, etc. Is to have helper methods on the entities themselves. Since Hibernate uses reflection you don't actually need to implement public getters and setters to your private members.

So for example your accessor for InstructorDetails `Instructor` class can look like:

```
public class Instructor {

    ...
    @OneToMany
    private List<InstructorDetails> instructorDetails;

    public Optional<InstructorDetails> getInstructorDetails() {
        if (instructorDetails == null || instructorDetails.size() == 0) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else if (instructorDetails.size() > 1) {
            // Optional raise if you want to be aware of corrupt Instructors that have many details
            throw Exception("There's corrupt data");
        } else {
            return Optional.of(instructorDetails.get(0));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Makes sense? Same for add ... you can have an add that takes a single detail, checks if there's one already and overwrites or throws, but internally it deals with the list. Whoever deals with `Instructor` will never know there's a list holding them inside.

Comment: No that is not what i want. I wanted a @OneToOne mapping. This is not the answer what  i wanted.

Comment: There is only one instructor detail associated with an instructor. So there is no point of having a List of instructor details here.

Comment: @JotWaraich I realize that. Which is why so that your parent/child relationship stays to whoever uses `Instructor` and `InstructorDetails` as a "virtual 1-to-1", you create the getter like that `getInstructorDetails()`. Which always returns 1 InstructuorDetails, not a list. I 100% understood your question.

Comment: There will be a much more elegant solution than this one that will use `@OneToOne` and `@MapsId` annotations. So i am not expecting an answer using `@OneToMany`